# Cannot use a find function inside a return function in react redux project

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I tried to use a find function inside the return function of the react component. but it is not working
the error report shows anonymous function.
What i tried to do is fetching the 'product' and 'category' from the API through redux and display the list of product along with the category name instead of the categoryid stored in the product object
**THE QUESTION IS HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK
   category = categories.find(category => category.id === product.category)
**

```
    import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import {useSelector,useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchProduct} from '../../../actions/product.actions'
import {fetchCategory} from '../../../actions/category.actions'
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'


const ProductList=()=>{
    const productsData=useSelector(state=>state.products)
    const categoriesData=useSelector(state=>state.categories)
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    const category={}
    const categories=categoriesData.categories[1]

    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(fetchProduct())
        dispatch(fetchCategory())


    },[])

    const findCategory=(categoryId)=>{
    return categories.find(category => category.id === categoryId)
    }

    return productsData.loading ?(

        <h2>Loading</h2>
    ): productsData.error?(
        <h2>{productsData.error}</h2>
    ):(
        <div>

            <Table striped>
                <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Category</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Brand</Table.HeaderCell>
                    <Table.HeaderCell>Model</Table.HeaderCell>        
                </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body>
                    {
                        productsData.products.map(product=>{
                            category = categories.find(category => category.id === product.category)      

                            return(

                                <Table.Row key={product.id}>
                                    <Table.Cell>{product.name}</Table.Cell>
                                    <Table.Cell>{category.name}</Table.Cell>
                                    <Table.Cell>{product.brand}</Table.Cell>
                                    <Table.Cell>{product.model}</Table.Cell>
                                </Table.Row>
                            )
                        })
                    }


                </Table.Body>
        </Table>
        {console.log(categories)}
        {console.log(productsData) }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductList
```

Comment: Don't quite understand the question, can you create a sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually mention *what* the error is you're seeing (other than it occurs in an anonymous function), but I suspect it is some "cannot access * of undefined", either *in* the find function callback itself, or in the return value of the map function.

**Undefined in Find Callback?**

```
category = categories.find(category => category.id === product.category)
```

Here it appears only `product` *can* be undefined when trying to access `product.category`. By definition `category` has to be defined since it is from mapping over `categories` array.

**But** for the same reason we know we can check `category.id` we know `product` is defined from the outer map callback anonymous scope and checking `product.category` is safe.

**Undefined in Map Callback?**

```
productsData.products.map(product=>{
  category = categories.find(category => category.id === product.category);      

  return (
    <Table.Row key={product.id}>
      <Table.Cell>{product.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{category.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{product.brand}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{product.model}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  )
})
```

So we've determined that both `product` from the map function callback and `category` from the find function callback should be defined we're left with the find function's return value. `array::find` returns `undefined` if no elements match the predicate and are found in the array. You should guard for this.

```
productsData.products.map(product=>{
  category = categories.find(category => category.id === product.category);

  if (!category) return null;

  return(
    <Table.Row key={product.id}>
      <Table.Cell>{product.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{category.name}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{product.brand}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{product.model}</Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>
  )
})
```

`null` *is* valid renderable JSX, but mapping an array to null values may seem odd

**NOTE:** This doesn't preclude the fact that there could be an external issue where either of the arrays being iterated over are for some reason undefined, but that could mean you don't have good default prop values, or your reducers return undefined initial values (or both).